# npx create-npx-module returns npm install exited with non-zero code: 127

Tags: node.js, npm, expo, yarnpkg

I have an Expo app and I want to create an Expo module.

I use the following command:

```
npx create-expo-module my-module
```

This command returns the following error:

```
✖ Installing module dependencies
Error: npm install exited with non-zero code: 127
    at ChildProcess.completionListener (/root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:42:23)
    at Object.onceWrapper (node:events:627:26)
    at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at maybeClose (node:internal/child_process:1098:16)
    at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:304:5)
    ...
    at spawnAsync (/root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/@expo/spawn-async/build/spawnAsync.js:7:23)
    at installDependencies (/root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/create-expo-module/build/packageManager.js:9:37)
    at /root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/create-expo-module/build/create-expo-module.js:64:56
    at newStep (/root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/create-expo-module/build/utils.js:21:22)
    at Command.main (/root/.npm/_npx/62900f925a4b91dc/node_modules/create-expo-module/build/create-expo-module.js:63:31) {
```

My versions are:

```
node --version
v19.8.1

npm --version
9.5.1

yarn --version
3.5.5

Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
```

I have tried with Node 16.x and Node 18.x, resulting into the same error everytime. I have also tried with `yarn create expo-module my-module` as well.

This topic has already been reported here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/20018 but I could not find any relevant answer for resolution (using Node exact version 16.0.0 creates other issues; anyway, I guess `npx create-expo-module` should work with latest versions of Node).

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 1):

Steps that fixed this issue for me on Mac (For Ubuntu see issue two - perhaps it's not possible to test IOS app on Ubuntu but issue one should be enough for you to code without the example app ios you can just use example app android) :
Please note that there are two steps that can fail this fixed both for me:

1. Failure at the "Installing module dependencies" step
2. Failure at the "Installing dependencies in the example app" step

The example app is created automatically by the expo module bootstrapper

**Steps I took that fixed issue 1:**

1. `rm /Users/mac/package.json`
2. `rm /Users/mac/yarn.lock`
3. `cd ~`
4. `yarn set version classic`
5. `cd Documents`
6. `yarn create expo-module my-module` (don't use npx ... not sure why this is how I made it work)

**Steps I took that fixed issue 2:**

1. Install XCode (The XCode CLI tool kit is sadly not enough on its own)
2. Open XCode > Preferences > Location if no path is shown under Command Line tools just reselect the path